# Using QGIS (or PostGIS), determine which network featureIds are shortest path between two points

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a network layer, and a layer of target start/end points (both as coordinate sets and as start feat_id and end feat-id).
like:
featid, geom
and
start_coord_x, start_coord_y, start_featid, end_coord_x, end_coord_y, end_featid
(although really "start" and "end" don't matter for this case, and I could use either the input coord sets or the respective featids)

I'm trying to determine the shortest path featid's that connect the two points. I have found many QGIS tools that will give me the shortest path as associated with cost, but none I have tried report back the exact featids used to create that shortest path.

Has anyone found a tool that will do this?

Comment: Since you have mentioned PostGIS, you can have a look at PG_Routing

Comment: @JGH Thank for your the idea. I checked the PG db's and they do not have this extension installed. I'll request it, but since I don't own/control the db I'm not sure the turnaround time.